# Low Seg2cat Doesn't Work With EE2.8.1

Tags: low-seg2cat

I've used low seg2cat on loads of websites in the past without issue. I just tried to set it up on a pretty much vanilla EE 2.8.1 site (only plugins Matrix, Playa, Freeform, Wygwam) and it doesn't seem to be working.

On the front end, none of the extension tags are being parsed (i.e. "{last_segment_category_id}"). In fact if I do a php exit in the extension file, nothing happens on the front end (it will exit if I try to access the control panel though).

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling without any luck just in case something went wrong.

Comment: I happened to just now finish testing an EE2.8.1 site with extensive use of Low Seg2cat, and it is working perfectly. That probably does not help you very much, so maybe if you had some code, we could try to replicate?

Comment: Same thing, i'm using this plugin with ee2.8.1, it's working fine.

Comment: What happens if you just place that seg2cat variable on the page? Wrap it around a tag that you can easily see.

Comment: They're not being parsed, so it'll just show i.e. "{last_segment_category_id}" on the page. And I know how this sounds, so yes the plugin is installed :P